# Redirecting to a web UI from Postman API calls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am executing an ASP.net Web API which is finally redirecting to a Web URL. I am doing this via Postman. The scenario is slimier to authentication API which is finally redirect to a Login UI.

When I execute the API nothing is happening. It is not even hitting the API it self. When I execute the same API URL via Browser it is working fine.

Why this is not happening and is there any setting in Postman which enables this? Is there any API test tool which covers  this scenario?

Edit : Note that these APIs are SAML SSO related APIs. But when we disregard the SAML factor, this is kind of normal web API, which finally redirects to a web page.

Thanks in advance.
Darshani

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net Web API function should return JSON data and for Authentication you should use Bearer Token.

Comment: Thanks,Actually this is not about the API. This is when testing the API via Postman. Also add to your point Asp.net web apis not only support JSON, we can use XML as well. also for authentication we can use any mechanism, we do not want to stick to Bearer Token. We can use custom authentications as well.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this:-

1. First thing, is that if we are setting the valid authentication token in the header so that API is accessible.
2. Second, if your site is hosted on some domain then check which email id you are login into your Postman.
   As it happened to me, for my project I need to login to Postman with 'domain.com' to access API.

Comment: Hi @Vartika Khandelwal, Thanks for the info.Now I am getting the html page, just the code content as the API response. but what i want is to redirect to the real page and insert some form values from there submit. This whole thing I want to do it in Postman.